# How to mock internal calls with mockery

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I try to mock a method of my service with Mockery lib. It works if I call that method from the test's context. But if I call it from another method (for example, it calls from another tested method) - it returns original data from implementation, but not from mock. What I'm doing wrong?
The example is below.

I added contract's because of my real implementation uses it. I don't think the problem is related to interfaces.

app/Contracts/TransactionsServiceContract.php

```
namespace App\Contracts;

interface TransactionsServiceContract
{
    public function getAllRequests(): array;

    public function getRequests(array $necessaryFields): array;
}
```

app/Services/TransactionsService.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\TransactionsServiceContract;

class TransactionsService implements TransactionsServiceContract
{

    public function getAllRequests(): array
    {
        return [
            'foo' => [
                'metric' => 'foo',
            ],
            'bar' => [
                'metric' => 'bar',
            ],
            'another' => [
                'metric' => [
                    // Some fields
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getRequests(array $necessaryFields): array
    {
        // dd($this->getAllRequests()); // -> for the test context it returns original value (above's one)
        return collect($this->getAllRequests())->only($necessaryFields)
            ->map(function (array $metric) {
                return $metric['formula'];
            })
            ->toArray();
    }
}
```

tests/Feature/TransactionsServiceTest.php

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Contracts\TransactionsServiceContract;
use Tests\TestCase;

class TransactionsServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @var TransactionsServiceContract */
    private $_transactionsService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $requests = [
            'test1' => [
                'metric' => 'test 1',
            ],
            'test2' => [
                'metric' => 'test 2',
            ],
        ];
        $this->_transactionsService = \Mockery::mock(app()->make(TransactionsServiceContract::class))->makePartial();
        $this->_transactionsService->shouldReceive('getAllRequests')->andReturn($requests);
    }

    public function testInternalCall()
    {
        $directCall = $this->_transactionsService->getAllRequests(); // returns array "requests" from the setUp method
        dump($directCall);
        $internalCall = $this->_transactionsService->getRequests(['test1']);
        dd($internalCall); // if we call getAllRequests into getRequests, but not from test's context, we get original array from real implementation, but not test's mock
    }
}
```

Versions of libs/frameworks:

- Laravel: v5.7.19
- PHPUnit: 7.5.1
- Mockery: 1.2.0

Thanks for attention. Happy new year! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `\Mockery::mock(app()->make(TransactionsServiceContract::class))->makePartial();` in your `setUp` method, you're not really replacing the implementation existing in the app container. Laravel's container provides you with the bind method, to do that ([the documentation for that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding)). Besides you wouldn't replace an interface with a mock, as interfaces don't do anything per definition.
So in fact you would do something like:

```
app()->bind('\App\TransactionsService', $mockedTransactionService);
```

> Note this will only work if your code gets an instance of the TransactionService by injection or resolving, not by calling `new TransactionService`.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
In other words, I cannot mock methods of the class which will be returned from DI, right?
So, I need to create an instance $mockedTransactionService (via new), mock methods and then bind it to my contract?

Well, yes. It makes sense because the test file is created for testing exactly implementation.

Thanks for your help!